# How to call IOS Custom render every time when I click a StackLayout(Having Gesture Recognizer) which is inside a ListView

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am trying to build a marquee for ios so I have written a custom Label render and used animation to achieve marquee and I am calling custom Label inside a stackLayout(stackLayout is inside a ViewCell of List). this StackLayout  has a gesture Recogniser.
On click I want Marquee to get called every time so I can start and stop marquee on the gesture click.Renderer is not being called every time we click the view?
It only gets called when the ViewModel constructor is called. How do I make the renderer get called everytime I click on the gesture of Stack Layout. Below is the code I have tried.

Xaml Page:

```
 <DataTemplate>
     <ViewCell>
     <StackLayout x:Name="MarqueeLabelGestureView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                                          <controls:MarqueeLabelLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  />
                                                                              <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                                                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference ResourceListView}, Path=BindingContext.OnMarqueeClicked}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                                              </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>                                             
                                                                      </StackLayout>
     </ViewCell>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Custom Render Code:

```
    namespace VCS.FieldManager.UI.iOS.CustomRenderer
{
   public class CustomLabelRender:LabelRenderer
    {
        public CustomLabelRender()
        {

        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                UILabel marqueelabel = Control;
                marqueelabel.Frame = new CGRect(40, 40, marqueelabel.Frame.X + 200, 40);

                     MessagingCenter.Send("", "OpenMarqueeLabel");
                if (!GridEntryViewModel.isMarqueeClicked)
                {
                    UIView.Animate(6, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear| UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat,
                  () =>
                  {
                       UIView.SetAnimationRepeatCount(1);
                      marqueelabel.Transform = CoreGraphics.CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation(-100,0);
                  }, null);
                    //  marqueelabel.Lines = 1200;
                }
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: expose a Start and Stop method on your MarqueeLabel, or use MessagingCenter to pass a start/stop message as needed.

Comment: Marquee is written in custom render class. that I am not able to call on gesture.